# Testing an app under multiple Windows user accounts

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, visual-studio-2015

I have a simple Windows 8.1 Universal app I created in Visual Studio 2015 under Windows login A. I now want to log in using Windows login B and run the app.

*problem*:

- The app isn't available for login B because it was deployed under login A's account.
- I can't deploy it in Visual Studio via login B because it's already deployed

Is this possible? I've tried running Visual Studio as administrator, but that doesn't work. I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately [Windows 8.1 deployment system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464929.aspx) has some buzzword like:

- Per user deployments
- App isolation
- Multi version existence

But we used some other way to solve this problem (not same but really similar)

- [Enterprise Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj657971.aspx)
- Login script (which tries to deploy your app via DISM)

(I know this is not the answer which is expected :/ )